# Bokeh latest version doesnt' support charts library for simply create a Boxplot

Tags: python, bokeh

I want to create an interative Boxplot in Google Colab with Bokeh.

I use Bokeh lastest version 2.4.2:

```
import bokeh
bokeh.__version__
```

=>    2.4.2

In previous Bokeh versions, it was possible to use:

```
from bokeh.charts import BoxPlot
```

to simply create a boxplot with 1 Python line (Cf https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-data-visualization-using-bokeh/).

But charts library is now deprecated in last version 2.4.2:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bokeh.charts'
```

For 2.4.2 version, I found this example for a Boxplot:
https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/gallery/boxplot.html

If I fine undestand, we have to compute ourself quartiles, outliers... for each category.
Do I right?
Does exist a method a little bit more simple?

I didn't find any Bokeh notebooks, including an example of a boxplot here:

https://mybinder.org/v2/gh/bokeh/bokeh-notebooks/master?filepath=tutorial%2F00%20-%20Introduction%20and%20Setup.ipynb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`bokeh` ditched their high-level chart interface quite some time ago because it was too much to maintain. Instead they adopted a different package that provided a high level charting interface called `Holoviews`

Holoviews works with many different renderers, but `bokeh` is the default, so you can have Holoviews create your plot objects, and then use `bokeh` to tweak/fine tune them.

https://holoviews.org/gallery/demos/bokeh/boxplot_chart.html#demos-bokeh-gallery-boxplot-chart.

Comment: Ok fine. So do you suggest me to use holoviews rather than Bokeh ? Or Bokeh is complementary?

Comment: Holoviews is built on top of Bokeh

Comment: @Theo75 Holoviews will get me 90-95% of the way for most of my visualizations. However, if you really want to make something aesthetically stunning, you can render the holoviews object to a bokeh object. So I'd suggest that you learn holoviews, and if you can seem to tweak it how you want, render it out into bokeh and go from there.